.Net MAUI load new page and wait for user response to continue exec Procedure
when I clicked a button (name button1) I need that load a page that has two buttons (like old VB6 MessageBox - OK / CANCEL) and stop the execution and wait for the user response.
Depending on the user response, I need continue the original execution or do other task.
I call the new page with next sentence
Application.Current?.MainPage?.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NewPage1());
I was try open the page mediant taskRun(...) or Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Dispatch(...) but the new page is not showing until that end the executions of procedure button1.
I will hope your help.
Thanks

You can use a popup from community toolkit and await the result for that and then do your next bit of execution. You can add all sorts of colors, play sound, buttons etc with that and is a better practice for UI as compared to a page for yes and no buttons

I can't stop the execution and show the popup.  Can you elaborate on what task you are performing?

If you only need to launch a dialog with 2 options and a message, you could use a DisplayAlert, which runs in an async method and waits for the user's response before continuing
bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
Debug.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer);

It looks like this:

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0

I made a page with special design of buttons and background, play sound when open the page (it read that is wrote in the page) and the result that return the page must be numeric.
This page is called from common procedure with parameters
Thanks for the example, but I would like show the message with a page.

Hi @Rodrigo, have you tried Popup?

Yes, I tried with Popup, but I have the same Problem. I can't stop the execution and show the popup. When I call it the popup with async, it keep running to the end of procedure
